# Borel measure generator

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure in $R$. In this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIF8XfMda4k&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxQVx5jRjbfRGEzWY_upS5K6&index=10 
it is said that if we specify the mesure to half open intervals $I=(-\infty,a]$ than we can specify to al other Borel sets.

How can we proof that?

Comment: You  can apply Caratheodory Extension Theorem.

Comment: If the measure is finite, then yes. Otherwise, evidently, no.

Comment: This follows from Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system